# Aligning two rasters of same resolution perfectly on top of each other in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, resolution, resampling, alignment

I have two rasters, that I managed to make in the same resolution using the 'Raster tools --> Resampling' tool by SAGA. The pixel sizes are exactly the same, however the new resampled raster, in the image it is the red, does not fall perfectly on top of the target raster (in blue).

[image]

I have checked that both rasters have the same CRS projection system, PIXEL size, dimensions, file type, but the only thing I see different is the Data Type. The Red is 'Byte' and the blue is 'Int32'. I have a feeling this difference is what is making my rasters not be aligned.

[image]

With the idea that this may be the issue, I have tried the following:

1. Re-doing the the 'Raster tools --> Resampling' tool once again to see if there is any indication or option where I can specify that I want my original red raster to be resampled as the target blue raster, in Int32. I have deselected the first option "Preserve data type" to accomplish this. However, this doesn't change much. (Also, choosing 'Cells' in the 'Fit' section instead of 'Nodes' only makes the pixels be further away from the raster I want to align with.)

[image]

2. Use the 'Align Raster' tool but I have greatly failed at this since it asks to resample two layers when I only want to resample 1. My outcome is basically the two rasters with values very different from the original rasters. Whenever I change any setting on that, it gives me a warning message that it "Failed to align rasters".

[image]

I seek help with this. I know with ArcGIS its easier to do but I only have QGIS.

Comment: Try gdalwarp https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#gdalwarp and see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378633/aligning-rasters-with-different-resolutions-and-crs

Comment: As you can see the extents and origins are slightly different. Using the extent of the first image as output extent for the second one should align them.

Answer (score 5):

I realized the 'Extent' was not exactly the same among my raster layers. I set the same Layer to give the exact coordinates for Extent and now they are aligned.

Answer (score -1):

I've got a tool that will automate aligning rasters in ArcGIS Pro - https://www.arcgis.co/home/item.html?id=4f5e9d4e3b974890991d33e7e5251231

See also https://gislandscapeecology.blogspot.com/2023/09/new-tool-align-rasters-toolbox-for_21.html

Comment: The question clearly mentions QGIS