# Pixels not matching with GDAL projection of Modis LST hdf data

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, modis, pixel

I have used the following the commands to project MODIS LST .hdf data through GDAL in cygwin:

```
gdalwarp -r bilinear -of GTIFF -tps -t_srs '+proj=utm +zone=29 +datum=WGS84' HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD11_L2.A2020053.2245.061.2021006023250.hdf":MOD_Swath_LST:LST test1.tif

gdalwarp -r bilinear -of GTIFF -tps -t_srs '+proj=utm +zone=29 +datum=WGS84' HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD11_L2.A2020053.1140.061.2021006022232.hdf":MOD_Swath_LST:LST test2.tif
```

The projections were successful, but when I open test1.tif and test2.tif in QGIS, the pixels don't match. I tried changing the resampling method but it made no difference.

Here is a screen print for you to see.

[image]

How can I make it so that the pixels match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is the same provided in this other question:

[Aligning two rasters of same resolution perfectly on top of each other in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381414/aligning-two-rasters-of-same-resolution-perfectly-on-top-of-each-other-in-qgis)

Answer (score 0):

Working with MODIS data, using GDAL didn't quite work as I expected and my tifs came out all funky. Are you sure your images came out alright? In my case I didn't get any errors but the projection wasn't right (even though it said it was). I figured out by loading the google satelite hybrid and the shorelines on my image weren't matching the shorelines on the hybrid.

If you don't absolutely have to use GDAL, try using [HEGTool](https://hdfeos.org/software/heg.php), it's a nice little utility program made by NASA specificaly for getting the tifs out of hdfs.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I tried HEGTool, but the result is the same. Pixels not matching for the same projection.